# asp.net mvc release will include a validation framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know how the validation will work with V1?  I'm at the crossroads, use one of the frameworks out there or wait for V1?

My asp.net mvc development has has been put on hold until i can find out more info on the v1 release and how the validation will support both the object model and ui??  Does anyone have info?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [ASP.NET MVC Design Gallery and Upcoming View Improvements with the ASP.NET MVC Release Candidate](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/12/19/asp-net-mvc-design-gallery-and-upcoming-view-improvements-with-the-asp-net-mvc-release-candidate.aspx#6798913)

> There are many other features and requests coming with the RC as well including: IDataErrorInfo support to enable models to surface validation error messages, as well as richer error validation extensibility to enable you to use your own approach to surface model validation errors to ModelBinders (the IDataErrorInfo support is built on top of this)

.

> >>> Are there plan to provide a way to provide client-side validation based on rules on the model or will this be up to the developer?
>
> We won't have this built-in with V1, although it is possible to build a library that adds it.  We are going to look into enabling some scenarios involving this in the future.
>
> Hope this helps,
>
> Scott

Answer (score 1):

We will support IDataErrorInfo as Scott Guthrie pointed out, but with 1.0 we will not have a full end-to-end validation story. The IDataErrorInfo support is a stopgap. Something that will meet the needs of some people, but not everyone.

We will hopefully have a prototype for the validation story sometime after the RTM.